# Animating windows.scrollby in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

So im using the window.scrollby like this

```
<script> 
function scrollWindowup()   {  
 window.scrollBy(0,700)   
 }  
 function scrollWindowdown()   { 
 window.scrollBy(0,-700)   }
 </script>
```

is there any way to animate it like move slowy or an offset or any other option ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From a similar question...

You can animate the `scrolltop` of the page with `jQuery`.

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".middle").offset().top
 }, 2000);
```

Or

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 700
 }, 2000);
```

Animating down a page:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: '+=700'
 }, 2000);
```

Animating up a page:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: '-=700'
 }, 2000);
```

See this site: 
http://papermashup.com/jquery-page-scrolling/

Comment: that code if is for moving to sections in a page , I just want it to move up or down by a fixed number of pixels with a little effect or animation .

Comment: You can set `scrollTop` to whatever value you want, it can be a fixed number of pixels.

Comment: I have a page roughly 3000px in height , and i wish to scroll 700px at a time in the upward and downward direction .. ScrollTop works but goes to the first 700px and not step by step .. also any way to scroll in the downward direction ? Excuse my noob questions i am just learning .. thanks a ton

Comment: Updated my answer. You can scroll up and down a page by using `+=` and `-=` with `animate`.